# Pushing data from Postgres 9.2 to a remote database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, sql-insert, dblink

I've used dblink several times in the past to pull information from a remote database into a local one.  However, I find myself wanting to do the opposite.  I want to PUSH from local to a remote.  Per the docs, I know you can do a:

`SELECT dblink_exec('myconn', 'insert into foo values(21,''z'',''{"a0","b0","c0"}'');');`

But, in the example above the insert is a string.

What I want to do is more dynamic.  I want to do something akin to:

```
INSERT INTO remote_table
SELECT a, b, c FROM local_table;
```

But, cannot find any examples of how to accomplish this task.

What is the best way to accomplish this?  Is this a case for using postgres_fdw (which I've never used)?

Currently using PostgreSQL 9.2

Answer (score 0):

`dblink` also ships [**`dblink_build_sql_insert`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib-dblink-build-sql-insert.html), which seems to fit your requirements exactly.

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib-dblink-build-sql-insert.html)

> `dblink_build_sql_insert` can be useful in doing selective replication
>   of a local table to a remote database. It selects a row from the local
>   table based on primary key, and then builds a SQL `INSERT` command that
>   will duplicate that row, but with the primary key values replaced by
>   the values in the last argument. (To make an exact copy of the row,
>   just specify the same values for the last two arguments.)

There is also a code example.

For a *whole table* I would run dblink in the remote db and *fetch* the data, since dblink is primarily for "executing a query in a remote database".
If restricted to *push* the data, I can only think of a loop in a plpgsql function right now.

Comment: yes. I saw that.  But, again it is for 1 record or statement.  If you want to do it over a result set, how would you accomplish?  Loop over in a function?

Comment: @DavidS: Added a something for that.

Comment: Thanks. It's not the whole table.  Maybe a few thousand records.  Could I accomplish this with dfw?